# iPad mini for testing iPhone apps

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

Tell me please, can I test on Ipad mini apps for iPhone with retina from Xcode? Or it is available only for iPad 3 and 4? I need the best way for testing, but can buy only one device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot test retina on iPad Mini due to the screen size/pixel density.

Answer (score 1):

You can test iOS applications on an iOS simulator on a Mac. You do not need to have any hardware to test the software, but you can only run apps on the hardware they're chose to run on. You cannot run iPad apps on an iPhone but you can run iPhone apps on an iPad.

Answer (score 0):

The iPad mini is non-retina, so no you cannot test the retina graphics on an iPad mini. You can however use the Simulator to test iPad and iPhone retina and non-retina.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should know if you didn't already that the simulator will let you run your app as if it were on all platforms.

Now as far as your issue goes. Sure, the iPad Mini will work. It's resolution is exactly the same as the first iPad. So when you install your app it will run the non-retina, iPad version of your app.

You can NOT test the retina graphics, as it does not have a retina display.

Hope that helps!